# Binary search program cause runtime error and failed hidden test cases

Tags: arrays, c, binary-search

I am practicing binary search with [problem 704 on leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-search/). At first, I just follow the concept of binary search and came up with this solution:

```
int search(int* nums, int numsSize, int target){
    size_t start=0, end=numsSize-1;
    while(start!=end){  // if start == end then break
        if(nums[(start+end)/2] > target){
            end=(start+end)/2;
        }
        else if(nums[(start+end)/2] < target){
            start=(start+end)/2+1;
        }
        else{
            return (start+end)/2;
        }
    }        
    if(nums[start]==target){    // when start == end
        return start;
    }       
    return -1;
}
```

It is not well-designed but it passed all test cases.

After that, I read some articles about binary search, I tried to reimplement it with this piece of code:

```
int search(int* nums, int numsSize, int target){
    size_t start=0, end=numsSize-1;
    while(start<=end){
        size_t mid = (start+end)/2;
        if(nums[mid]==target){
            return mid;
        }
        else if(nums[mid] > target){
            end=mid-1;
        }
        else{
            start=mid+1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The problem is it just pass 3/47 test cases and cause runtime error.

So what makes my second version cause error but my first version doesn't.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try nums=[7,8] and target=3;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing wrong with your second implementation is using `size_t`. Change it to `int`, and it ought to work fine.

`size_t` is an unsigned type. The value of `end` can be negative when the search is probing the beginning of the array.  This invokes undefined behavior in C.  In practice, that usually means the value "underflows" and becomes a huge positive number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my very short version:

```
int search(int* nums, int numsSize, int target){
    int lo=0;
    int hi=numsSize-1;
    
    int* x[]= {&lo, &hi};
    while(hi-lo>1)
    {
        int mid=lo+(hi-lo)/2;
        if (nums[mid]==target) return mid;
        *x[nums[mid]>target] = mid;
    }
    
    return (nums[lo]==target)? lo:
           (nums[hi]==target)? hi: -1; 
}
```